# rails link_to controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, action, link-to

I show in my homepage 4 pictures, and when a user click on one of it, I want to change a parameter :asked in my db.

In my view I've added

```
<%= link_to image_tag(friends.picture), {:controller => "static_pages", :action => "recomend", :id => friends.user_id} %>
```

In the Static_Pages_Controller I have

```
def recomend
  a = Friends.find_by_user_id(params[:id])
  a.update_attribute(:asked, true)
end
```

And in routes.rb

```
resources :static_pages do
 resources :recomend
end
```

but when I click on it, the server refresh my home (why?!) and in the server logs i see

```
Started GET "/auth/failure?action=recomend&controller=static_pages&id=101" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-17 19:59:25 +0100.
```

Comment: The auth failure tells me that there is more to the app than it seems - what is causing the auth controller to be hit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe it's not recognize the link. I suppose `friends.picture` is a link for image, so you can try this:

```
<%= link_to( "", :controller => "static_pages", :action => "recomend", :id => friends.user_id) do %>
  <%= image_path(friends.picture) %>
<% end %>
```